# What is a good design for Ranking System

Tags: database, mysql, ranking

I have a `USER` table, that has `userId` and `point` fields. At runtime, I want to know what is a ranking of a particular user base on their point. What is the best way to accomplish this:
1: Query all users into a list. Sort the list base on point and do a binary search to find the ranking of that user. Sound like a bad idea here.
2: Is it possible to accomplish these tasks by creating database queries?

I expect 2000-5000 users.

Comment: I think you need to re-phrase this.  How are you defining what "rank" means in your system?

Comment: @Peter: I would expect that the rank is the number of the user entry in the user list by `point`.

Comment: @Harry: maybe something like `select rn from (select userId, point, row_number() over order by point desc as rn from USER) where userId="whatever";`? (I am not really good in SQL syntax)

Comment: @Vlad mysql does not support windowing like that, afaik

Comment: make sure you do not calculate/sum total points in `real time`...

Comment: @ajreal: I dont think I do any sum at all. The `point`, is the total score accumulate over time. Are you saying that sum all the points will cause major overhead?

Comment: @Harry Pham - Yup, lots of rows to calculate will affect performance.

Comment: @ajreal: Thank you. I will definitely keep that in mind.

Comment: Why is this question labeled with jpql? You probably mean sql... please edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SET @rownum := 0;

SELECT rank, userId, point 
FROM (
       SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, userId, point
       FROM user ORDER BY point DESC
     ) 
as result WHERE userId = xxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you mind explain to me a bit on how you calculate the variable `rank` from your code. The above code, is it mysql syntax? Just that I never see `SET @rownum := 0;` before. +1

Comment: For sure, basically you are sorting your table according to the point right. And then what you want is to get the row number for each record. The `@rownum` variable does exactly that. At the end you get the record for your particular userid =)